# LazyColumn items mutual exclusive

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

Say I have a list of items in a `LazyColumn` and they can all be selected. How can I make sure when an item is selected, the others are deselected (so only 1 item can be selected at once)?

I was thinking about `interactionSource` but I'm not really sure how use it.

Comment: It depends on how you store the selected state, please add some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd extract this logic into a `ViewModel`, with your items being a specific UIModel that contains your current data of the items + their state, containing the `isSelected` state.

For ex:

```
data class YourUiModel(val id: Long, val isSelected: Boolean = false, ...)

private val _items = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<YourUiModel>())
val items: StateFlow<List<YourUiModel>>
    get() = _items
    
private fun changeSelectionTo(uiModel: YourUiModel) {
        _items.value = items.value.map { it.copy(isSelected = it.id == uiModel.id) }
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just store a variable holding the index of the selected variable

`var sel by mutableStateOf(0)`

Now you may want to use remember here if you are declaring it in your Composables, but I would highly recommend storing it inside a viewmodel. A simple example would be

```
class VM: ViewModel(){
 var sel by mutableStateOf(0) //Assuming 0 is selected initially, change it to -1 if you please

 //Create a setter optionally, for state-hoisting
 fun setSel(index: Int){
   sel = index
 }
}
```

In the MainActivity,

```
class MainActivity{
 val vm by viewmodels<VM>()
 setContent{
  MySelectableList(
     list = ...,
     selected = vm.sel,
     onSelectionChange = vm::setSel // Just pass the viewmodel if you did not create the setter
   )
 }

 @Composable
 fun MySelectableList(
    list: List<Any>,
    selected: Int,
    onSelectionChange: (int) -> Unit // or vm, if you did not create the setter
  ){
     list.forEachIndexed {index, item ->
       // Now create this Composable yourself
       ItemComposable(
          isSelected = index == selected,
          onClick = { onSelectionChange(index) } // Just focus and have a look at what's happening here
       )
     }
  }
}
```

I am using state-hoisting here, read [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#8) for reference. Def take this codelab if you haven't already

You will need to do an additional check if you set the initial value of sel to -1 earlier. Completely understand the code that is flowing through here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use remember {...}

```
@Composable
fun MyComposeList(data: List<MyItemData>,...) {
    val (selectedItem, setSelectedItem) = remember { mutableStateOf(null // or maybe data.first() } // remember current selected by state delegate

    lazyColumn() { // your lazy column
       items (data) { item -> // item = each item
          // your compose item view
          MyComposeItemView (
              data = item,  // pass data by each item
              isSelected = data == selectedItem // set is item selected by default
          ) {
              // on item click
              setSelectedItem(it)
           }
       }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyComposeItemView(
        data: MyItemData, 
        isSelected: Boolean, 
        onSelect: (MyItemData) -> Unit = {}) {
   
   // here set item selected state = isSelected maybe change color or something

  // assume we have box as single item
  Box(Modifier.clickable {
     onSelect(data) // cal on click function and pass current data as parameter
  })
}
```