# LazyColumn, Jetpack Compose. Single items() state by index

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have a problem with the state of individual elements in LazyColumn and LazyRow. If the first element is open and I want to delete it, then the second element becomes the first and also becomes open. I want it to work differently.

**Screen**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxwZH.gif)

**Fragment LazyColumn**

```
items(zamList.size) { index ->
                ExpandableCard()
            }
```

**Expandable Card**

```
@Composable
fun ExpandableCard() {

    //Expandable state
    var expandedState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Card(
        onClick = {
            expandedState = !expandedState
        }
    )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose LazyColumn - How to update values of each Item seperately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71817213/jetpack-compose-lazycolumn-how-to-update-values-of-each-item-seperately)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to combine LazyLists with remember:

Try adding 20 items, opening 1, and scrolling, until the item is not visible anymore: the item will have closed.

The way i suggest to do it is:
Hold that state in a viewModel, e.g. a Map<YourItem, isOpen>
onOpen/onClose update your viewmodel-state.

---

Other than that, it's a good idea to provide ids if possible.

---

Also, you might try `Modifier.animateContentSize()` (which is only defined in a `LazyScope`(!), so your animations look better :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [use unique keys](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance#use-lazylist-keys) with items. Using key will makes sure only the items that changed being recomposed and keeps order of items that are not changed based on their ids.

```
val myItems = listOf<MyItem>()

LazyColumn() {
    items(
        items = myItems,
        key = {item: MyItem ->  
            // Some unique id here
            item.hashCode()
        }
    ) {

    }
}
```